How do I only type the value and let TypeScript infer the key of an object?
I have an object with string as keys. But, I don't want it to be string. I want the key strings to be that exact value of the object. I have to type the value of that object as well to follow certain rules. Here is an example,
type ObjectValueType = {
  checked: boolean;
  fields: Path<Camera>[];
};

type ObjectType = Record<string, ObjectValueType>;

const Object: ObjectType = {
  camera_stream_endpoint: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['camera_stream_endpoint'],
  },
  layout_image: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['layout_image'],
  },
};

In the above object, I have created a typescript type ObjectType which has string as key and ObjectValueType as value. I don't want key to be string. I want the key to be the exact keys of the Object (camera_stream_endpoint or layout_image or rest). How do I infer this key?
I don't want to create a union type of the object key because that object is an extremely long object with a lot of keys. So, I would prefer TypeScript infer that key from the created object.
One thing I tried is using assertion as const like so
const Object = {
  camera_stream_endpoint: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['camera_stream_endpoint'],
  },
  layout_image: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['layout_image'],
  },
} as const;


The above achieves the desired outcome for the keys. But, now, I can put whatever I want for the value. Example, I could easily mess up the fields which should follow the defined type Path<Camera>. TypeScript won't complain at all for the wrong values.
I want to type the keys and values of the object. Keys should be inferred from the created variable and values will have their own type definition. Is it possible?

• Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about. Right now I don't know what Camera or Path is, so I can't be certain I understand the question. • If I assume that doesn't matter, then my suggestion looks like this playground link; if TS inference doesn't work the way you want by default, then you need a helper function to guide the inference. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (but please edit to resolve Path/Camera). If not, what's missing?

Thank you for your help. I will update my question accordingly and will get back to you if the playground resolves my issue.

One solution I can offer is to infer the keys from your const object, define the type that you need and they assign the const object to a variable of the desired type :
type ObjectValueType = {
  checked: boolean;
  fields: Path<Camera>[];
};

const ConstObject = {
  camera_stream_endpoint: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['camera_stream_endpoint'],
  },
  layout_image: {
    checked: false,
    fields: ['layout_image'],
  },
};

type ObjectTypes = keyof typeof ConstObject;

export type CustomObject = { [key in ObjectTypes]: ObjectValueType };

export const Object: CustomObject = ConstObject;

Note that you must remove the const assertion as it will narrow down the fields parameter too much for the object to be assignable to the newly created type.

You are not typing the value of ConstObject. Now, you can put whatever values you want for fields and checked . Typescript will not complain about it. I want to type the values as well. ConstObject is the source of true that will have all the keys and values. Keys should be fixed and values should be typed

That is correct, well I can see no other solution than creating an union type for all the possible keys, but then how are you making sure that the keys in the current object are correct ? The best that you can manage is to have the keys as constant values, but then what is the purpose, as you will still be able to add new keys to it.

Yeah, I think I will just create a Union type for all the possible key values. It's quite redundant though. But, seems like this is the only way.
Thanks for the help
